# R Markdown: is it possible to get all the code of an R chunk precede its output, instead than having an output for each line of code?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown document, with an R chunk containing 2 lines of code. In the resulting HTML document, I would like all the code lines belonging to the same chunk (two in this example) to be printed in a single box, before their output.

````
---
title: "Just a test"
author: "Yours Truly"
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'
output:
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(car)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE,
               out.width = "75%", 
               fig.align = "center")
```

here is some code
```{r EDA}
summary(Davis)
ggplot(Davis, aes(x = height, y = weight)) +
  geom_point()
```
````

Instead, what I get is that each line of code of the chunk is immediately followed by its output:

[image]

I want the two gray boxes containing `summary(Davis)` and `ggplot(Davis, aes(x = height, y = weight)) + geom_point()` to be joined together in a single gray box, followed by their output. Is this possible?

Comment: Add `results='hold'`to the code chunk.

Comment: @Alex it works! I'm not sure why the order of the output is inverted, i.e., the `ggplot` plot appears before the `summary`. Apparently, adding also `fig.show='hold'` solves the problem.

Comment: Can't you surround the code with matching curley braces?

Comment: @42- your solution doesn't work: the code is shown in a single gray box, which is good, but then the output contains only the plot. The summary is missing. You can implement your suggested fix and see for yourself that it doesn't work: maybe you could find a way to fix it?